# Stored procedure switch parameters because of switching lines in code

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I have a stored procedure which looks like this (do not read it since 80% is not related to this question so first read rest of it):

```
COMMIT WORK;
SET AUTODDL OFF;
SET TERM ^ ;

/* Stored procedures */

CREATE PROCEDURE "NAPRAVISTAVKU" 
(
  "VRDOK" SMALLINT,
  "BRDOK" INTEGER,
  "ROBAID" INTEGER,
  "CENA_BEZ_PDV" NUMERIC(15, 2),
  "KOL" NUMERIC(15, 3),
  "RABAT" NUMERIC(15, 2)
)
RETURNS
(
  "OK" SMALLINT
)
AS
BEGIN EXIT; END ^


ALTER PROCEDURE "NAPRAVISTAVKU" 
(
  "VRDOK" SMALLINT,
  "BRDOK" INTEGER,
  "ROBAID" INTEGER,
  "CENA_BEZ_PDV" NUMERIC(15, 2),
  "KOL" NUMERIC(15, 3),
  "RABAT" NUMERIC(15, 2)
)
RETURNS
(
  "OK" SMALLINT
)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE MAGACINID SMALLINT;
DECLARE VARIABLE MTID VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE VARIABLE NAZIV VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE VARIABLE TARIFAID VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE VARIABLE NABAVNACENA NUMERIC(15, 4);
DECLARE VARIABLE POREZ NUMERIC(15, 2);
BEGIN
  OK = 0;

  SELECT MAGACINID, MTID FROM DOKUMENT
  WHERE VRDOK = :VRDOK AND BRDOK = :BRDOK
  INTO :MAGACINID, :MTID;

  SELECT NAZIV FROM ROBA WHERE ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO :NAZIV;

  SELECT NABAVNACENA FROM ROBAUMAGACINU
  WHERE MAGACINID = :MAGACINID AND ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO :NABAVNACENA;

  IF (CENA_BEZ_PDV = 0) THEN BEGIN
    SELECT PRODAJNACENA FROM ROBAUMAGACINU
    WHERE MAGACINID = :MAGACINID AND ROBAID = :ROBAID
    INTO :CENA_BEZ_PDV;
  END

  SELECT TARIFAID FROM ROBA WHERE ROBAID = :ROBAID
  INTO TARIFAID;

  SELECT STOPA FROM TARIFE WHERE TARIFAID = :TARIFAID
  INTO :POREZ;

  INSERT INTO STAVKA (VRDOK, BRDOK, MAGACINID, ROBAID, VRSTA, NAZIV, NABCENSAPOR, FAKTURNACENA, NABCENABT,
              TROSKOVI, NABAVNACENA, PRODCENABP, KOREKCIJA, PRODAJNACENA, DEVIZNACENA, DEVPRODCENA, KOLICINA,
              NIVKOL, TARIFAID, IMAPOREZ, POREZ, RABAT, MARZA, TAKSA, AKCIZA, PROSNAB, PRECENA, PRENAB, PROSPROD,
              MTID, PT, TREN_STANJE, POREZ_ULAZ, DEVNABCENA, POREZ_IZ)
  VALUES (:VRDOK, :BRDOK, :MAGACINID, :ROBAID, 1, :NAZIV, 0, 0, 0, 
           0, :NABAVNACENA, :CENA_BEZ_PDV, 0, :CENA_BEZ_PDV, 0, 0, :KOL,
           0, :TARIFAID, 0, :POREZ, :RABAT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
           :MTID, 'P', 0, 0, 0, :POREZ);

  SUSPEND;

  /* Obrada greske */
  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN
    OK = -1;
    SUSPEND;
  END

END
 ^

SET TERM ; ^
COMMIT WORK;
SET AUTODDL ON;
```

Inside my C# code I execute it like this:

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
{
    con.Open();

    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("NAPRAVISTAVKU", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VRDOK", vrDok);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BRDOK", brDok);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ROBAID", robaId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CENA_BEZ_PDV", (cenaBezPDV == null) ? 0 : cenaBezPDV);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KOL", kolicina);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RABAT", (rabat == null) ? 0 : rabat);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("OK", FbDbType.SmallInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["OK"].Value);
        return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["OK"].Value);
    }
}
```

The problem (which I solved) is that for some reason inside my table 2 columns were switched (both I am passing): `CENA_BEZ_PDV` and `KOL`

I have been hitting my head for about 3hrs to find out what the problem was. I was using *rubber ducking* multiple times and couldn't find logical explanation why it is not working and then dumb inside me told to try switching 2 lines.

So before switching two lines my code looked like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ROBAID", robaId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("KOL", kolicina);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CENA_BEZ_PDV", (cenaBezPDV == null) ? 0 : cenaBezPDV);**
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RABAT", (rabat == null) ? 0 : rabat);
```

And then I switched 2 lines where I am passing `KOL` and `CENA_BEZ_PDV` with logic *Let's make it order just like in stored procedure* and boom it worked.

Would someone please explain me why this happened? Totally same code just swapped lines so it meets order like in stored procedure and it worked.

Does even this naming parameters mean anything or code just add parameters in order of parameters of procedure?

Maybe this is not Firebird or SQL problem but c#?

Comment: In Firebird itself, when executing, parameters are always positional, not named. Any translation between named parameters from C# to the positional parameters expected by Firebird would need to be done by the Firebird ADO.net provider. It looks like this is not done, I'm not sure if that is a bug or not. You may want to consider asking on the Firebird .NET driver mailing list instead.

Comment: Note that [this issue](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-148) suggests it is by design, but that was a long time ago, so maybe that has changed.

Comment: I have read that and i guess that it really is only position based. I will try tomorrow with random names of parameters on same procedure and see if it execute.

Comment: Alternatively, see what happens if you prefix the parameters with an `@`. But again, consider asking on the Firebird .NET driver mailing list.